# Cyclic SwapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: ethereum, solidity, uniswap

Is it possible to call `SwapExactTokensForTokens` on any one of the popular DEX Routers in such a manner that I get the **same token out as I put in**. For example:

USDC → DAI

DAI → USDT

USDT → USDC

The `SwapExactTokensForTokens` works with multi-hops, but fails when I try to make it cyclic.

Has anyone had success calling this function on a smart contract and receiving the same token back?

Comment: Cycle swaps do not make sense. What's the error you are receiving?

Comment: It makes sense if you want to do arbitrage